# DJI Gimbal - how to get callbacks from hardware buttons when pressed

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I'm working on a camera app using Android Camera2 SDK which has button for start/stop recording, and a zoom functionality. I've integrated the DJI mobile SDK and I did the registration with the API key generated from the developer account. When I start the app, I receive a `REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` from `DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback()#onRegister()` and the Gimbal is connected through Bluetooth to the phone.

Now the issue is, how can I intercept the hardware button press events from the Gimbal ? For example if I press the hardware record button of the Gimbal, the camera app starts recording.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work. I couldn't find any documentation about how to receive callbacks when hardware buttons are pressed.

```
OSMOMobileHandheldController osmoMobileHandheldController = new OSMOMobileHandheldController();
    osmoMobileHandheldController.setHardwareStateCallback(hardwareState -> {

        switch (hardwareState.getRecordAndShutterButtons()) {
            case IDLE: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getRecordAndShutterButtons IDLE");
                break;
            }
            case RECORD_CLICK: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getRecordAndShutterButtons RECORD_CLICK");
                break;
            }
            case SHUTTER_CLICK: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getRecordAndShutterButtons SHUTTER_CLICK");
                break;
            }
            case SHUTTER_LONG_CLICK: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getRecordAndShutterButtons SHUTTER_LONG_CLICK");
                break;
            }
            default: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getRecordAndShutterButtons UNKNOWN");
            }
        }
        
        switch (hardwareState.getZoomState()) {
            case IDLE: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getZoomState IDLE");
                break;
            }
            case ZOOM_IN: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getZoomState ZOOM_IN");
                break;
            }
            case ZOOM_OUT: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getZoomState ZOOM_OUT");
                break;
            }
            default: {
                Log.e(TAG, "getTriggerButton UNKNOWN");
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just create an object. You must call the sdk to get the correct instance.
You have only created an object that is not connected to anything.

https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html#djisdkmanager_product_inline

So something like:
DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct().getHandheld()
will get you an object that is connected to the api

Comment: Thx for the reply, I did like you said 
`HandHeld handHeld = (HandHeld) DJISDKManager.getInstance().getProduct();
        handHeld.getHandHeldController().setHardwareStateCallback(new HardwareState.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(HardwareState hardwareState) {
            }
        });`
In the log I see that handHeld is of time `OSMOMobile` which is correct because its my Gimbal.
but it didn't work, when I press the button I receive nothing.. 
It would be awesome that you could help me with this, thank you!